# Use results of query as a column names

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables, one with data and one with sensor names, the other with log data from several sensors on different tests.
The sensor name changes from test to test.

I wanto to select the sensor name from the sensors table and query the data table using sensor name as the column name something like :

```
d2 as (select colname from tbl_sensornames where test='xxx' and sensor=2) from tbltests
```

I cant do this offcourse, but i think you get the general ideia.

My plan was to use a function to get the col name but my efforst have gone noware.

my code is :

```
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
result_value TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT name INTO result_value FROM tbl_test01_channelinfo WHERE channel = id_value AND testid = name_value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select * from select_holi_value(101,'MIImlRpwBJlC') into my_var;

select d101 as my_var from tbl_test01;
```

can any1 help here ?

thanks

Comment: Use a [PREPARE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-sql-prepare.html) statement. ("PREPARE prepares a statement dynamically specified as a string for execution. This is different from the direct SQL statement PREPARE, which can also be used in embedded programs. The EXECUTE command is used to execute either kind of prepared statement." )

Comment: You could look into [crosstab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#id-1.11.7.52.5.5) or use [dynamic SQL in a plpgsql routine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). Note that a routine's direct output structure has to be either fully predefined or specified at call time - it can't change column names and types on its own between calls. It's that or two-step calling, where you first call the routine and then execute a statement that routine prepared, or let it dump its output to a table that you'll pick it up from.

Comment: It would be easier to assist with this if you presented a minimal reproducible case: **1)** paste a `create` statement for both of these tables, **2)** provide some sample data in the form of two `insert` statements, **3)** present the exact code you tried and the result it gets you **4)** create a mock/fake/example result you're aiming to get instead.

Comment: 1) You say you have 2 tables then you say *...one with data and one with sensor names, the other with log data*. That looks like 3 tables to me. 2) You need to show the complete function code. From what you do show there is not `RETURN result_value` to actually return anything from the function. 3) Where is `my_var` coming from in `select * from select_holi_value(101,'MIImlRpwBJlC') into my_var;`?